# MySQL and PHP using rank by ASC

Tags: mysql

Trying to fix ranking off scores table, I put this in;

```
SELECT * from scores where tournament_id = "3" AND class = "MA1" ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

It came out

```
1
11
12
13
2
22
3
31
4
5
6 and on, how can it be fixed?
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of your Rank  field? Is it integer type?

Comment: It's varchar(3) by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rank column data type is string. So it is returning as above please convert it in number or int format.

```
SELECT CAST("10" as SIGNED) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `rank` column is a textual column (e.g., `varchar`), and therefor, when you order by it, you order **lexicographically**. If you want to sort it **numerically**, you need to explicitly convert it:

```sql
SELECT   * 
FROM     scores
WHERE    tournament_id = "3" AND class = "MA1"
ORDER BY CAST(rank AS INTEGER) ASC
-- Here -^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from scores 
  where tournament_id = "3" 
  AND class = "MA1" 
ORDER BY CAST(Rank AS INTEGER) ASC
```

You should casting the type char to int your rank field for order by